# Plugin on all site except primary one

Tags: plugins, multisite

I'm using Wordpress multisite on a SAAS project and I want to create a plugin which deals with my custom post types. I want them to be accessible on all sites except on the main site. Do I have to just check blog_id ?

Thanks !

Comment: Please [edit] your question and replace the `(---)` with what you are trying to check. It seems you posted the question but accidently left that bit out :)

Comment: WordPress Multisite has a conditional function that checks for that -- [`is_main_site()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_site).